# Is there any display bigger than 15 cm (6 inches)?

Tags: display

I'm looking for a display to show 2 single lines of text, at least 15cm (6 inches) to be conected to my raspberry pi.

I don't mind if display is LCD or OLED, or any.. I don't need touchable device.

The only thing I found is those LCDs for 16 or 20 characters, but they are too short. Double of that would be perfect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search for a product (shopping recommendation) is off-topic per site rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They make an HD44780 compatable display (this is what the LCD you mention likely is most are) that comes in [2 rows by 40 characters](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2051541.m570.l1313.TR11.TRC2.A0.H0.X2x40%20lcd.TRS1&_nkw=2x40%20lcd&_sacat=0). They even have [4x40](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=2x40%20lcd&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X4x40%20lcd.TRS1&_nkw=4x40%20lcd&_sacat=0) and [4x20](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=4x40%20lcd&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR3.TRC2.A0.H1.X4x20%20lcd.TRS0&_nkw=4x20%20lcd&_sacat=0) models.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any tutorials how to install does?

Comment: @carduque assuming you have an hd44780 compatible LCD (most of them are) this should get you started https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview